# How to set project version to all projects for multimodule projects (with Versions-Maven-plugin)?

Tags: maven

I have a multi module project that goes deeper then level 1. I'm starting to use 'versions-maven-pluging'.

From my topmost parent pom I ran :

> mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=13.0.2

Then I got these (sample) pom files for the topmost parent and it's first child module:

***Level 0***

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>_parent-company</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>

    <modules>       
        <module>../subproject1</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

***Level 1***

```
<project>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>_parent-company</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.2</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>_parent-subproject1</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>       
        <module>../subproject1.1</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

***Level 2***

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>_parent-subproject1</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.subproject1</groupId>
    <artifactId>_parent-subproject1.1</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

When I check the module of the parent in level 0, I see the version is unchanged. Then, the version in level 1, was changed so that is ok. Finally, in the level 2 project, nothing changed.

If I get to the level 1 parent directory, I can run a command to update the child submodule of this level (but not without errors since the repo was not updated for parent 13.0.2).

> mvn versions:update-child-modules

Is there a way to change everyone from first parent to the lowermost leave project? For now we are building a single version of everything so no need to create versions for each parent.

Is there a simple workflow that could make simpler? For now this is what I'm about to do:

1- Manually change the version of the topmost parent.

Run theses (in level 0 directory):

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=13.0.2
mvn -N install
```

Run theses (in level 1 directory):
    mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=13.0.2

Strangely enough, when I run version:set in level 1, I get the proper result. The parent and  all children project POMs are set with version 13.0.2. Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever solved this issue, im facing the same?

Comment: Yes (if I recall correctly), I noticed the first time you implement versioning you need to set your hierarchy at each level. Seems the 'version:set' will check if the child has the same version as the parent. You are trying to set, say version 1.0, the POM vesion has to match version 1.0, otherwise it will skip the version set.